# The namespace `XDrawing.TestLab.Tester' already contains a definition for `TesterBase'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, namespaces

Have found a few answers to this question but none seem to work for my case. I can't really figure out whats wrong or how to fix it. I'm trying to use PDFsharp in unity and it's giving me the above error, here's the code that's raising the issue:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using PdfSharp.Drawing;

namespace XDrawing.TestLab.Tester
{
/// <summary>
/// Base class for all Tester classes.
/// </summary>
public abstract class TesterBase
{
public TesterBase()
{
  this.properties = XGraphicsLab.properties;
}

public virtual void RenderPage(XGraphics gfx)
{
  //Debug.WriteLine("RenderPage");
  //gfx.Clear(this.properties.General.BackColor.Color);
  //DrawGridlines(gfx);
  gfx.SmoothingMode = XSmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
}

protected XFont CreateFont(string familyName, double emSize)
{
  XFont font;
  try
  {
    font = new XFont(familyName, emSize);
  }
  catch
  {
    font = new XFont("Courier", emSize);
  }
  return font;
}

protected XFont CreateFont(string familyName, double emSize, XFontStyle style)
{
  XFont font;
  try
  {
    font = new XFont(familyName, emSize, style);
  }
  catch
  {
    font = new XFont("Courier", emSize, style);
  }
  return font;
}

protected XFont CreateFont(string familyName, double emSize, XFontStyle style, XPdfFontOptions options)
{
  XFont font;
  try
  {
    font = new XFont(familyName, emSize, style, options);
  }
  catch
  {
    font = new XFont("Courier", emSize, style, options);
  }
  return font;
}

protected void DrawGridlines(XGraphics gfx)
{
  XPen majorpen = XPens.DarkGray.Clone();
  majorpen.Width = 1;
  XPen minorpen = XPens.LightGray.Clone();
  minorpen.Width = 0.1f;
  gfx.SmoothingMode = XSmoothingMode.HighSpeed;
  DrawGridlines(gfx, new XPoint(100, 100), majorpen, 100, minorpen, 10);

  string text = this.Description;
  XFont font = new XFont("Verdana", 14, XFontStyle.Bold);
  XSize size = gfx.MeasureString(text, font);
  gfx.DrawString(text, font, XBrushes.Black, (600 - size.Width) / 2, 30);
}

public abstract string Description {get;}

protected GraphicsProperties properties;

protected static PointF[] Pentagram
{
  get
  {
    int[] order = new int[] { 0, 3, 1, 4, 2 };
    if (pentagram == null)
    {
      pentagram = new PointF[5];
      for (int idx = 0; idx < 5; idx++)
      {
        double rad = order[idx] * 2 * Math.PI / 5 - Math.PI / 10;
        pentagram[idx].X = (float)Math.Cos(rad);
        pentagram[idx].Y = (float)Math.Sin(rad);
      }
    }
    return pentagram;
  }
}
static PointF[] pentagram;

protected static PointF[] GetPentagram(float size, PointF center)
{
  PointF[] points = Pentagram.Clone() as PointF[];
  for (int idx = 0; idx < 5; idx++)
  {
    points[idx].X = points[idx].X * size + center.X;
    points[idx].Y = points[idx].Y * size + center.Y;
  }
  return points;
}

protected const double Deg2Rad = Math.PI / 180;

public void DrawGridlines(XGraphics gfx, XPoint origin, XPen majorpen, double majordelta, XPen minorpen, double minordelta)
{
  RectangleF box = new RectangleF(0, 0, 600, 850);
  DrawGridline(gfx, origin, minorpen, minordelta, box);
  DrawGridline(gfx, origin, majorpen, majordelta, box);
  /*
        float xmin = -10000f, ymin = -10000f, xmax = 10000f, ymax = 10000f;
        float x, y;
        x = origin.X;
        while (x < xmax)
        {
          DrawLine(majorpen, x, ymin, x, ymax);
          x += majordelta;
        }
        x = origin.X - majordelta;
        while (x > xmin)
        {
          DrawLine(majorpen, x, ymin, x, ymax);
          x -= majordelta;
        }
        y = origin.Y;
        while (y < ymax)
        {
          DrawLine(majorpen, xmin, y, xmax, y);
          y += majordelta;
        }
        y = origin.Y - majordelta;
        while (y > ymin)
        {
          DrawLine(majorpen, xmin, y, xmax, y);
          y -= majordelta;
        }
   */
}

[Conditional("DEBUG")]
void DrawGridline(XGraphics gfx, XPoint origin, XPen pen, double delta, XRect box)
{
  double xmin = box.X, ymin = box.Y, xmax = box.X + box.Width, ymax = box.Y + box.Height;
  double x, y;
  y = origin.Y;
  while (y < ymax)
  {
    gfx.DrawLine(pen, xmin, y, xmax, y);
    y += delta;
  }
  y = origin.Y - delta;
  while (y > ymin)
  {
    gfx.DrawLine(pen, xmin, y, xmax, y);
    y -= delta;
  }
  x = origin.X;
  while (x < xmax)
  {
    gfx.DrawLine(pen, x, ymin, x, ymax);
    x += delta;
  }
  x = origin.X - delta;
  while (x > xmin)
  {
    gfx.DrawLine(pen, x, ymin, x, ymax);
    x -= delta;
  }
}
}
}
```

Thanks for any light you can shed on this!

Comment: Is this Unity3d? You probably meant Unity in the tag.

Comment: yeah this is in Unity3d

Comment: Do a search in the project panel for TesterBase. Second solution, Shift-Cmd-F (Ctrl-Alt-F) and enter TesterBase. This will show you if for some reasons you may have twice the same file or twice the naming.

Answer (score 0):

You have **two** classes with **the-same name** in **the-same namespace**.

You have **XDrawing.TestLab.Tester** as the namespace and **TesterBase** is the class name the compiler is **complaining** about. You need to look in your every `.CS` file in your project and make sure that they do **NOT** have any class named **TesterBase**.